# How to store, restore and add to JSON file, SQLite database or text file?

Tags: json, flutter, sqlite, local-storage

When I learned that no file could be modified inside the assets folder I did the following:

1. Use a variable to store data. How to call it again?
2. Using SQLite shows the same problem and error messages.
3. Store the data and call it from a text file, but it is also useless.

Error messages:

- Sometimes the application hangs during the build phase at this line in the terminal:

  > Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1
- Using `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` either with a JSON file or SQLite:

  > Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
- Trying to store or read from text file:

  > Unsupported operation: _Namespace

My attempts:

```
{ 
    "user" :[
    {
        "name":"sife",
        "age":44
    },
    {
        "name":"hasan",
        "age":22
    }
]
}
```

I want to add this:

```
"name":"faris",
"age":30
```

I want an example that can be applied with the lowest specifications and the least libraries and complexity.

Comment: did you try creating a model class to store the values in a list and then retrieve the values from the list using toJson function?

Comment: yes i do put i get nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample example, if you want me to explain this, feel free to comment and ask for explanation

```
class UserList {
  List<User> userList;

  UserList({required this.userList});

  factory UserList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var userList = json['user'] as List;
    List<User> users = userList.map((userJson) => User.fromJson(userJson)).toList();
    return UserList(userList: users);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'user': userList.map((user) => user.toJson()).toList(),
    };
  }
}

class User {
  String name;
  int age;

  User({required this.name, required this.age});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      name: json['name'],
      age: json['age'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'age': age,
    };
  }
}
```

```
void main() {

  Map<String, dynamic> json = {
    "user": [
      {"name": "sife", "age": 44},
      {"name": "hasan", "age": 22}
    ]
  };
  UserList userList = UserList.fromJson(json);

  userList.userList.add(User(name: "faris", age: 30));

  Map<String, dynamic> updatedJson = userList.toJson();
  print(updatedJson);
}
```

Comment: Naqeeb abid  Great job, thank you, but your favor will be complete, my teacher, when I can use it in the following way...
A button to save the new addition of data from two text fields, and another button to display the data in a list, and where this data will be stored. I do not care where I care that when the application is opened again, the newly entered data will be present ...

Thanks again and I wish you success

Comment: Also, I want to understand why it does not work for me to connect to the sqlite database in Flutter, especially

Answer (score 0):

I used Mr. Naqib's intervention and asked the artificial intelligence site to merge what the professor wrote with what I want specifically, so the result was as follows.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class UserList {
  List<User> userList;

  UserList({required this.userList});

  factory UserList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var userList = json['user'] as List;
    List<User> users = userList.map((userJson) => User.fromJson(userJson)).toList();
    return UserList(userList: users);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'user': userList.map((user) => user.toJson()).toList(),
    };
  }
}

class User {
  String name;
  int age;

  User({required this.name, required this.age});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      name: json['name'],
      age: json['age'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'age': age,
    };
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<User> userList = [];

  void _saveData() async {
    // Create a UserList object and add the current list of users
    UserList userListObject = UserList(userList: userList);

    // Convert the UserList object to a JSON object
    Map<String, dynamic> json = userListObject.toJson();

    // Get the directory where the file should be saved
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    // Create the file
    final file = File('${directory.path}/users.json');

    // Write the JSON data to the file
    file.writeAsStringSync(jsonEncode(json));

    // Show a snackbar to indicate that the data has been saved
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text('Data saved successfully'),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showData() async {
    // Get the directory where the file is saved
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    // Open the file
    final file = File('${directory.path}/users.json');

    if (!file.existsSync()) {
      // Show a snackbar to indicate that the file doesn't exist
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('No data found'),
        ),
      );
      return;
    }

    // Read the JSON data from the file
    String jsonString = await file.readAsString();

    // Convert the JSON data to a UserList object
    Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    UserList userListObject = UserList.fromJson(json);

    // Update the list of users
    setState(() {
      userList = userListObject.userList;
    });
  }

  void _addUser() {
    // Create a new User object and add it to the list of users
    User user = User(name: 'New User', age: 0);
    setState(() {
      userList.add(user);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('User List'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: userList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final user = userList[index];
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(user.name),
                    subtitle: Text('Age: ${user.age}'),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _saveData,
                  child: Text('Save'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _showData,
                  child: Text('Show Data'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _addUser,
                  child: Text('Add User'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: But as usual the same problem    Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

Comment: Is your issue resolved? Can you provide your imports in pubspec.yaml, Have you imported the path_provider package into your pubspec and your files where you are trying to access it?

Comment: Yes, for all of the above, I imported the necessary libraries originally, and if you did not download them, the test run would not start....

My good brother, you solved the problem only to appear on a list without storing this data, because you did not put anything related to the save path or the name of the file to be saved in, until I put these instructions in a button to be saved. You understood , but it is incomplete. Regarding the default storage path and file, and the save code, not the save code in JSON inside the code, but rather in an external file,

Comment: void _addUser() {
    // Create a new User object and add it to the list of users
    User user = User(name: 'New User', age: 0);
    setState(() {
      userList.add(user);
    });
  }
  .... Nothing here is related to saving new data or adding it to an external file, so this is like writing in the sand, when the application is closed and then started again, nothing but the feed that you made in the code for the data and not the actual execution time of the application